# Is it possible to combine to lambdaas which have the same body?

Tags: c#

```
myEntry.Unfocused += async (s, e) =>
                {
                   // Same code
                }

myButton.Clicked += async (s, e) =>
                {
                   // Same code
                }
```

Is it possible to combine these tow lambdas in order to avoid maintaining the same code twice?

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These events are effectively assigning a method to call once invoked. As long as the signature matches, you can point it directly at a named method

```cs
myEntry.Unfocused += OnEvent;
myButton.Clicked += OnEvent;

private async Task OnEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Just ensure the return type is correct.